# Matplotlib dual x-axis logarithmic ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I've set the upper x-axis manually (the conversion is 1.218x the values on the lower x-axis) and I'd like the upper ***minor*** logarithmic ticks to move up the scale by 1.218x too. Any suggestions?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

X = np.linspace(0,10000000, 1000000)

ax1.semilogx(X, zero, label='$\mathbb{P} (X=0)$')
ax1.semilogx(X, one, label='$\mathbb{P} (X=1)$')
ax1.semilogx(X, two+more, label='$\mathbb{P} (X\geq2)$')
ax1.set_xlabel(r"Particle Concentration m$^{-3}$")
ax1.set_ylabel(r"Probability of occurrence")
ax1.legend(loc=6)
ax1.grid()

ax2.semilogx(X, one, label='one', alpha = 0)
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_xticks([12.18323586744639, 121.8323586744639, 1218.323586744639, 12183.23586744639, 121832.3586744639, 1218323.586744639])
ax2.set_xticklabels(['10$^1$','10$^2$','10$^3$','10$^4$','10$^5$','10$^6$'])
ax2.set_xlabel(r"Disdrometer Particle Count (min$^{-1}$)")

plt.show()
```

[image: Poisson pmf for raindrops inside an instrument]

Comment: Have you tried using a [LogLocator](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator)? I didn't ever try re-using the same tick locator on two axes but perhaps worth checking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Rewriting after your comment below.

There will be a way to move the minor ticks but actually I think your approach here is misguided. Looking close you aren't using `ax2` to plot anything: you just want it as an alternative scale. You are messing with the ticks and ticklabels when as a way of faking changing the limits. It would be much easier to just change that limits (so that matplotlib can handle the ticks etc automatically).

Replace your code above with

```
ax2.set_xscale("log", nonposx='clip')
ax2.set_xlim(np.array(ax1.get_xlim())/1.218)
```

Comment: Apologies, the upper major ticks are lined up to the upper numbers correctly, but the upper minor ticks match the lower x-axis which is incorrect. If you look closely you'll see the gap between the highest minor tick and the major tick is much larger than the lower x-axis. I've amended the question accordingly - Thanks

Comment: Oh, okay. Actually I think I see a better approach to your problem. Will update the answer